# Match all repeating occurrences regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match following string separated by whitespaces starting with **"Token"** .
Example string

```
Token token=12eqddsfasdsa user_email=user@mail.com app_id=2312edsdas
```

I have tried several expressions.

```
^Token (\w*=[^-\s]+)
```

Captures only one first match.

```
^Token(\s\w*=[^-\s]+)+
```

This expression captures only last.

I need to capture

```
match[0] = token=12eqddsfasdsa
match[1] = user_email=user@mail.com
match[2] = app_id=2312edsdas
```

I know there is easy way to achieve this result, but I am not experienced enough to get it.
Please help with this.

Comment: I can just split value pairs in php code. I need to get entries as I described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the common problem of capturing content for repeated groups, so 
I would use two regexes for this:

1- First to detect the line starting with `Token` pattern using this regex:

```
^Token
```

2- To extract the matches you are interesting in using another regex (like yours):

```
(\w*=[^-\s]+)
```

You can use a code like this

```
$str = <your string>
if (preg_match("/^Token/", $str)) {
    preg_match_all('/(\w*=[^-\s]+)/', $str, $matches);
}
```

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [6-25]  `token=12eqddsfasdsa`
MATCH 2
1.  [26-50] `user_email=user@mail.com`
MATCH 3
1.  [51-68] `app_id=2312edsdas`
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, the only one thing, it returns array of two elements, they are exactly the same subarrays.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple way is using explode function.

```
$str = "Token token=12eqddsfasdsa user_email=user@mail.com app_id=2312edsdas";
$result = explode(" ", $str);
```

The result will be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => "Token" [1] => "token=12eqddsfasdsa". [2] => "user_email=user@mail.com"  [3] => "app_id=2312edsdas")
```